# choson and kallah a week before their wedding

Tags: minhag, marriage

There seems to be a commonly accepted מנהג for a חתן and כלה not to see each other the week before their wedding. When did this מנהג start? What is the reason for this מנהג? Are there any exceptions? (cases where the חתן and כלה should be seeing each other during that time)